# Ng test error, Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

After running `ng test` I received this error:

> ng-virtual-main.js!=!data:text/javascript;base64,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
>
> - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
>   Error: data:text/javascript;base64,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
>   is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in
>   your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

Karma Server, starts but does not run any tests and displays the above error in the console. Can someone help me figure out why it happens?

This is my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.5"
    ...
}

  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    ...
    "typescript": "~4.9.3",
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Apparently, the problem is a bug in Angular. It may be fixed soon, but it's caused by this line in the tsconfig.json:

```json
"allowJs": true,
```

As soon as I set it to `false`, the tests started running for that project.

Original:

I'm running into the same problem. I just decoded the Base64 in the error message and it seems to be test setup code:

```js
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting,
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
    
// Initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting(), {
  errorOnUnknownElements: true,
  errorOnUnknownProperties: true
});
```

Granted. I'm no closer to figuring out the problem, but I'm hoping this might help someone understand it.

Comment: If you need allowJS to compile your application, you could put `AllowJs = false` in the tsconfig.spec.js to impact only the test phase.